# Why jQuery $.ajax is working very slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jquery

I am using this code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "CSProcessing.aspx/ReadyRTicketsForSale",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{ 'reservationNo' : '" + resNo +
     "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: rloadticketsS,
});
```

This code returns result correctly but very slow i want fast execution.
Please give any suggestion any suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: Run a browser debugger like Firebug in Firefox or the Chrome inspector that lets you watch the network requests.  Verify that the issue is the time between when the HTTP request is sent to your server and when the response is received.  Once verified, you have nothing further to do in the browser - go fix the server to respond faster.

Comment: It's not your JS code, but more likely your _server is responding slowly_? Or, `CSProcessing.aspx/ReadyRTicketsForSale` is performing a big task causing it to respond slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code hasn't anything to do with the Javascript - Its your server that's responding slowly.

Make sure its not getting stuck in loops longer than it needs to, etc. make sure your server is configured correctly, THEN crack open the profiler.

Answer (score 1):

there are several tips that you must doing for fast execution.

for example: compress your .js file, quality source code and Sql query in the server side. also, you can link to these links in follow instead of use js lib in your page:

```
1. Google Ajax API CDN – http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
2. Microsoft CDN – http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
3. jQuery CDN – http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
```